# MVC 5 ReturnURL for External Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Does anyone know how / where to set the returnUrl parameter that's passed to: the AccountController on an ASP.Net MVC 5 application:

```
// POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's typically carried along in the query string, imagine that you require Authorized logged in users for your "Manage" page, so when a user clicks on the manage page, it does a redirect to the login page with the return url set to the "Manage" page.

Specifically, its the CookieHandler/Cookie OWIN middleware that is doing the redirect to the login page and automatically appending the current Uri to the query string for the returnUrl.